# How can I use tf.contrib.signal in tf v1.1

Tags: tensorflow

As title mentioned. Shows Attribute Error: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal' now. And another questions is it possible update contrib folder only?

Comment: Please read before you post any more to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.contrib.signal` library is not part of TensorFlow 1.1: it was added to TensorFlow in [release 1.3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.3.0). You will need to upgrade to a newer version of TensorFlow to use that library.